# Is a comma required in 'No thanks' when it means 'No, but thanks anyway'?

Tags: punctuation

Is this correct without a comma after 'No'?

> Mike: Would you like a slice, Joe?
>   Bob: No thanks.
>
> April: Would you like a beer?
>   Amy: No thank you.

Context seems clear to me without a comma in each.

Comment: Are you trying to conserve characters, or is there some other motivation for wanting to omit the comma? There's probably not *too* much chance that you'll be misunderstood,  but that one little punctuation mark will ensure that the sentence is read *No, (but I) thank you (just the same)* rather than as *(I offer) no [‘]thank you[’]*.

Comment: "No thanks" is commonly said without any hint of a pause, and thus there is no need for the comma, in most uses.  There is little danger of it being misinterpreted in a reasonable context.  "No, thank you", on the other hand, is probably more appropriate with the comma -- there is generally a hint of a pause after "no".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should there be a comma after "no" in "no thank you"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/272157/should-there-be-a-comma-after-no-in-no-thank-you)

Comment: See also: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/272157/should-there-be-a-comma-after-no-in-no-thank-you

Answer (score 2):

It is not required. 
If using "No thanks" which is shortened for thank you. 
If using "No, thank you" there is a pause and sounds more formal with the comma.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! Can you flesh out this answer and add some references? Take the [Tour] and see [answer] for more.